# When typing Korean in IntelliJ, the cursor is at the front of the text,

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

Sorry, picture is so small...

I want cursor is behind text like to type english,

first time using intellij in my life..

hellp me,

Comment: Cursor is OS-managed. What OS do you have?

Comment: i use Window 11

Comment: What input method do you have? In Windows, there are plenty of hieroglyphic input methods.